# Extract value from PHP array and echo on HTML page multidimensional response from Curl script

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP. I have the following array, I would like to understand how to request a single variable, and echo on my html page:

```
Array
(
    [DATI_TOPOGRAFICI_RICHIESTI] => Array
        (
            [COMUNE] => CUNEO
            [PART_TOP] => VIA
            [STRADA] => ROMA
            [CIVICO] => 10
        )

    [CORREZIONI_DATI_TOPOGRAFICI] => Array
        (
            [STRADA] => ROMA ==> ROMA
        )

    [RISULTATI_NNI] => Array
        (
            [Copertura FTTC NNI] => NO
            [Copertura FTTH NNI] => SI
            [Profilo Massimo FTTH NNI] => 1000
            [Copertura FTTH OPEN FIBER] => NO
        )

)
Array
(
    [RISULTATI_NGA_TELECOM] => Array
        (
            [Copertura FTTC NGA TELECOM] => SI
            [Profilo Massimo FTTC NGA TELECOM] => 100
        )

)
```

I have try:

```
  echo $response['DATI_TOPOGRAFICI_RICHIESTI']['COMUNE'][0];
```

But the response is always A.

What can I try to resolve this?

### Update

This is the PHP code that generate the array: file = api.php

```
$risposta_NNI = Array (
        DATI_TOPOGRAFICI_RICHIESTI => Array ('COMUNE' => $COMUNE, 'PART_TOP' => $gPart_Top, 'STRADA' => $gStrada, 'CIVICO' => $gCivico),
        CORREZIONI_DATI_TOPOGRAFICI => Array ('STRADA' => $gStrada. ' ==> ' .$STRADA),
        RISULTATI_NNI => Array('Copertura FTTC NNI' => $COPERTURA_FTTC,
        'Copertura FTTH NNI' => $COPERTURA_FTTH , 'Profilo Massimo FTTH NNI' => $PROFILO_MAX_FTTH,
        'Copertura FTTH OPEN FIBER' => $COPERTURA_OF_CD),
        );

        print_r($risposta_NNI);


$risposta_NGA = Array (
  RISULTATI_NGA_TELECOM => Array('Copertura FTTC NGA TELECOM' => $COPERTURA_FTTC_NGA, 'Profilo Massimo FTTC NGA TELECOM' => $PROFILO_MAX_FTTH_NGA,));

  print_r($risposta_NGA);
```

and this is the call PHP curl to retrieve the response:  - file index.php

```
$curl = curl_init();


        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://attivazioni.infosys.it/copertura/api.php?token=token&comune=$citta&part_to=$part_to&strada=$indirizzo&civico=$civico",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "VIEW",
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
```

this is the response:   print_r($response);

```
Array ( [DATI_TOPOGRAFICI_RICHIESTI] => Array ( [COMUNE] => CARAGLIO [PART_TOP] => FRAZIONE [STRADA] => VALLERA [CIVICO] => 72 ) [CORREZIONI_DATI_TOPOGRAFICI] => Array ( [STRADA] => VALLERA ==> VALLERA ) [RISULTATI_NNI] => Array ( [Copertura FTTC NNI] => SI [Copertura FTTH NNI] => NO [Profilo Massimo FTTH NNI] => 0 [Copertura FTTH OPEN FIBER] => NO ) ) Array ( [RISULTATI_NGA_TELECOM] => Array ( [Copertura FTTC NGA TELECOM] => SI [Profilo Massimo FTTC NGA TELECOM] => 100 ) )
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? $response is not a defined variable.

Comment: @ruandas: the question is now updated per your comment.

Comment: $response is defined on index.php om the call curl

Comment: Solved, i missed echo json_encode($risposta_NNI); on api.php and             $array = json_decode(trim($response), TRUE); on index.php and then $comune = $array['DATI_TOPOGRAFICI_RICHIESTI']['COMUNE']; . Thanks

Comment: Alain: would you format your `print_r()` please, over several lines? Readers won't horizontally scroll through that amount of output. (It is easier to copy it to your clipboard again, and then wrap it in triple-backticks, than it is to add formatting to it again manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code I'd say that to access the request you are sending, you need the `$risposta_NNI` variable.

```
echo $risposta_NNI['DATI_TOPOGRAFICI_RICHIESTI']['COMUNE'];
```

The response from the api looks like this:

```
echo $response['RISULTATI_NGA_TELECOM']['Copertura FTTC NGA TELECOM'];
```

Comment: Sorry but the $risposta_NNI is on the api.php file my call curl is on index.php and the response of curl arrive on $response i have tried all two commands but i print always A

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($response)`?

Comment: print_r($response)                                                                                                     
Array ( [DATI_TOPOGRAFICI_RICHIESTI] => Array ( [COMUNE] => CARAGLIO [PART_TOP] => FRAZIONE [STRADA] => VALLERA [CIVICO] => 72 ) [CORREZIONI_DATI_TOPOGRAFICI] => Array ( [STRADA] => VALLERA ==> VALLERA ) [RISULTATI_NNI] => Array ( [Copertura FTTC NNI] => SI [Copertura FTTH NNI] => NO [Profilo Massimo FTTH NNI] => 0 [Copertura FTTH OPEN FIBER] => NO ) ) Array ( [RISULTATI_NGA_TELECOM] => Array ( [Copertura FTTC NGA TELECOM] => SI [Profilo Massimo FTTC NGA TELECOM] => 100 ) )

Comment: Solved, i missed echo json_encode($risposta_NNI); on api.php and $array = json_decode(trim($response), TRUE); on index.php and then $comune = $array['DATI_TOPOGRAFICI_RICHIESTI']['COMUNE']; . Thanks